# Binary to Decimal in Haskell without using recursion or list comprehensions

Tags: haskell

I am currently working on a homework assignment that requires me to implement a function that converts binary to decimal without using list comprehensions or recursion.

I've tried using folds, explicitly using `foldr`, to implement this, but can't quite get correct results. In a [related thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48438257/convert-binary-to-decimal-haskell) I have found the following

```hs
bintodec :: [Bool] -> Int
bintodec = foldr (\x y -> fromEnum x + 2*y) 0
```

which seems like a good starting point, but does not seem to produce correct results for me. It seems to work for any given odd number, where the list only consists of `True`s, yet not for anything else.

The assigned function is also supposed to have this signature:

```
binarytoInteger :: [Bool] -> Integer
```

which I tried to achieve using the above definition by using the `toInteger` function at various points, but could never actually match the type of the function definition.

I would gladly appreciate a hint in the right direction!

Comment: Well in your `bintodec`, it works with the first `Bool` the *least significant bit* (LSB).

Comment: `foldr (\x y -> (if x then 1 else 0) + 2*y) 0 . reverse`.

Comment: `foldr` is recursive. Do you just mean that you're not allowed to use explicit recursion?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware of that, should have clarified. No explicit recursion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> which seems like a good starting point, but does not seem to produce correct results for me. It seems to work for any given uneven number, where the list only consists of Trues, yet not for anything else.

It works, in the sense that it indeed converts a binary list to an integer. But in your function the *first* element is the *least significant bit (LSB)*.

We could for example use a `fold` here:

```
import Data.Bool(bool)

bin2dec :: (Foldable f, Integral i) => f Bool -> i
bin2dec = foldl (\a -> (+) (2*a) . bool 0 1) 0
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [False]
0
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True]
1
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, False]
2
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, True]
3
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, False, False]
4
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, False, True]
5
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, True, False]
6
Prelude Data.Bool> bin2dec [True, True, True]
7
```

Comment: so I essentially approached this "from the wrong side", given that both the comments and this answer either uses `reverse` or `foldl`? And how would I now go about changing your solution towards the required type signature of the function that I have to create?

Comment: @cluu: the type signature is more general, so `bin2dec` can support `[Bool] -> Int`, `[Bool] -> Integer`, etc.

Comment: @cluuu: `foldl` runs over the list conceptually left-to-right, whereas `foldr` runs conceptually right-to-left.

Comment: That seems clear now, just one last thing: the bool part. A quick search tells me it replaces an `if p then y else x` statement, what would be my `p` in this particular case?

Comment: `bool y x p` is the same to `if p then x else y` indeed, so here `p` is the *eta-reduced* parameter in the lambda-expression.

Comment: Though this seems a little tedious, since this assignment calls for no imports, what would be a way to incorporate this?

Comment: @cluuu: you can simply define your own `bool` function.

Comment: @cluuu Your `fromEnum` is fine. No need to use `if` or `bool` if you don't wanna. Just call `fromIntegral` after to convert from `Int` to `Integer` (or whatever other `Num` type).

Comment: @DanielWagner thanks for the tip! that made it a bit more clear for me.